# which side should I validate the form data, client side or server side?

Tags: spring, security, validation

At first, I intend to get the validation done on the client side by javascript or jquery, something like that, but then I realize that some malicious users may skip my jsp page, sending data which is not been validated to my servlet. My server end is structured using Spring+SpringMVC+mybatis, is there any way that I can keep the validation on client side, as well as keep my server safe(does spring security help?).Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **always** validate on the server side.

Validation on the client side is only for convenience of your (honest) users and adds nothing to the security of your system.

The server-side validation must always be done and nothing will make your server automatically safe (safe from what? **you** have to decide what input is safe for your application, your database, your users, how it will be used etc.).

The only easy way to reuse your client-side validation code on the server side is to use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or other server-side JavaScript like [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino).

Comment: is there any article about how to use Node.js to run javascript on server side, especially combining with spring framework? thx!!

Comment: Basic principle of web programming: assume all requests are evil and check them accordingly.

Comment: @Judking You may find Rhino to be easier to integrate with Spring since it is also a server-side JavaScript engine like Node.js but it is itself written in Java. See [Rhino in Spring](http://rhinoinspring.sourceforge.net/) and [How to run JavaScript from Java](http://springinpractice.com/2012/05/13/how-to-run-javascript-from-java/) and [google for: java spring rhino](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+spring+rhino)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, you need to validate server side to keep it safe.

Any thing you do client side can be undone by a malicious user. Generally, client side validation is used for quicker feedback to the user and to prevent your server getting too many hits. So it is still very beneficial, but you will need both.